# Hide Bootstrap collaspe button on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this code to create a collapse.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I hide or move the collapse button at the end on click?

Regards,
Ibadullah

Comment: Do you want to make modifications on the button after the collapse animation is done?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best way but probably using the onclick attribute might work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" onclick="$('#test').fadeOut();">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make actions/modifications when collapse animations are finished, is using listeners on the events they trigger:

- Event **show.bs.collapse**: This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
- Event **shown.bs.collapse**: This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).
- Event **hide.bs.collapse**: This event is fired immediately when the hide method has been called.
- Event **hidden.bs.collapse**: This event is fired when a collapse element has been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

I let you and example where I play with the CSS of the button using listeners on these events: **shown.bs.collapse** and **hidden.bs.collapse**.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").css("opacity", "0.5");

    // Register a listener for collapse events.
    
    $('#demo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function()
    {
        $("button").css("opacity", "1").removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-primary");
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function()
    {
        $("button").css("opacity", "0.5").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.